# Tail bounds for maximum of chi-squares

Tags: probability

Suppose one has $n$ i.i.d. chi-square variables $X_i$ with degrees of freedom $k$. Is there any literature on the distribution of $\max(X_i)$?

In particular are there any good tail-bounds for the distribution?

Comment: What do you mean by 'different'?  If $X \sim Chisquared(v)$, do you mean that $X_i \sim Chisquared(v_i)$, OR that the sample of size $n$ are iid and all drawn from the same distribution with SAME parameter $v$?

Comment: I edited the question. You have one chi-square distribution with $k$ degrees of freedom, and $n$ draws from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n)$ denote a random sample of size $n$ drawn on $X \sim \text{Chisquared}(k)$, with common pdf $f(x)$:

[image]

The pdf of the sample maximum is the pdf of the $n^{th}$ order statistic, say $g(x)$, namely:

[image]

where I am using the `OrderStat` function from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica* to automate the calculation. The domain of support is the positive real line.

All done.

To illustrate, here is a plot of the pdf of the sample maximum $g(x)$, at different values of $n$:

**When k = 5:**

[image]

**When k = 10:**

[image]

**Notes**

1. `Gamma[a,z]` denotes the incomplete gamma function $\int _z^{\infty } t^{a-1} e^{-t} d t$.
2. As disclosure, I should perhaps add that I am one of the authors of the `OrderStat` function used above.